# Как получить Image в Jetpack Compose из строки с названием файла?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

У меня есть большое количество картинок которые хранятся в папке assets. Как можно получить картинку из такой картинки, по аналогии с открытием обычного файла, в стиле
Image(File("mypic.jpg"))

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека [coil-compose](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil#jetpack-compose) умеет загружать картинки из assets. Чтобы подключить эту библиотеку, добавьте следующую зависимость в ваш проект:

```
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.3.0'
```

Теперь, картинки из assets можно загружать следующим образом:

```kotlin
AsyncImage("file:///android_asset/mypic.jpg", null)
```